# useState hook does not update when value is set by JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, ionic-framework

I got an input field that I fill via JS for end-to-end testing.

```
document.getElementById("textfield").click()
document.getElementById("textfield").value = "test"
```

Unfortunately the useState hook updates only when I manually type in another character.

Is there a way to simulate my typing (already tried it character by character with .value) or how do I solve that issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"I got an input field that I fill via JS for end-to-end testing."* There are special libraries for testing React components. If you have to use whatever you are currently using, try to dispatch an input or change event on the element instead.